# Making java tooltips disappear with application switch

Tags: java, tooltip

I use JComponent.setToolTipText to get tooltips in my java application, but unlike, e.g., eclipse, if I switch to another application when a tip is showing, it remains hovering over what I'm doing until I switch *back* to the java app and move the mouse around to get it off the element before returning to the alternate application.  Is there a way to make the tooltips in my app better citizens?  to make them disappear when the app loses focus?

I'm on a mac if relevant.

Comment: Are you using lightweight or heavyweight tooltips? [Check with TooTipManager.sharedInstance().isLightWeightPopupEnabled(), or set with sibling setLightWeightPopupEnabled(boolean).]

Comment: It's lightweight. Which do I prefer? Are there pros and cons of each?
I tried switching it to false with the setter and didn't see a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution! (with some input from a colleague)

```
<myJFrame>.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {

        @Override @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setEnabled(false);
        }


        @Override @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

A WindowAdapter listening to windowActivated/Deactivated also works.
A plain FocusListener does not.